# Is there a way to change the anyDensity Manifest settings run-time?

Tags: android

In my manifest, I have "anyDensity" set to false, but for some devices I need to set it to "false".  Is there any way to change this on my main activity's "onCreate"?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Android Manifest is supposed to be immutable especially since [the marketplaces use it to decide what devices that your app supports](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html).

Why does it work on one screen and not another of exactly the same type, what is the actual problem?

Comment: I have an app I wrote a year ago, and it uses anyDensity=false and has one set of MDPI graphics.  With anyDensity set to false, the screen scales automatically on most devices.  HOWEVER, it does not work this way on Tablets, in which case I have need anyDensity set to true, and I create a Bitmap that is scaled while the app is running.  If anyDensity stays at true, then the scaling breaks.